# Add link to mysite for all users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, my-site, mysite

Once our users visit their mysite we have no obvious link back to the main site, is there an easy way to add this for all users? I want to add a link for users but cant see an easy way via the UI or indeed via the Master Page

Comment: Would you like to place a home link on the site logo? Or do you have any thing in mind?

Comment: Would adding a promoted site into the Sites tile of the app launcher work?

Comment: Yes I think that would but ideally would like it in the left hand nav...

Comment: For some reason our account does not have the option to add a custom tile...is this only for certain Licenses?